# How to use low competition keywords with large search volume effectively?

Tags: google, google-search-console, keywords, seo

How to use low competition keywords with large search volume effectively?

For example :

I have keyword phrase "why does the" which produce 368,000 global searches (searxch type : phrase in google keyword tool). This keyword has 1% competition.

I want to know what can I do with this keyword.

NOTE: The phrase is the starting phrase, ex: why does the sun shine?, why does the moon's color white?
why does the sky blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't do anything with that keyword. It's **very** broad. This gives you a couple of problems:

1. Unless you have a lot of content related to why things do what they do you will have users arrive at your site only to find that the content they are looking for is not there. That will produce a high bounce rate. It also will not encourage other webmasters to link to your site which is important for SEO.
2. The 1% figure you have is bogus. No one may target that exact phrase but you can be sure there are a lot of sites targeting phrases that include "why does the" in them. As a result they will ranking well for their search phrase *and* "why does the" by extension since the page's content and incoming links will include that phrase.

Comment: Thanks John, however, can you explain "As a result they will ranking well for their search phrase and "why does the" by extension since the page's content and incoming links will include that phrase." ONE more time. Please!!!

Comment: Pages can rank for a virtually unlimited amount of search phrases. So by optimizing a page for "why does the sun shine" will also help it be optimized for "why does the" and also "sun shone" since that phrase is included in the copy and incoming links for that page. It will be more targeted for "why does the sun shine" then "why does the" but it will still have a chance to rank for both phrases, and others as well.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration!!!!! always appreciate you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If your site is centered on this single question "why does the...", you could name it like this. A domain name like `www.why-does-the.org` would probably make your site interesting for such queries.

Comment: whydoesthe.com/sun-shine
whydoesthe.com/moon-effect-tides

would be a very clean site url structure

Comment: Or drop $180,000 on a gTLD so you can have why-does.the/sun-shine :)